# Pandas dataframe doesn't update column value under condition

Tags: python, pandas

Originally I have a dataframe (along with other columns, but the information is not relevant here)

| index | DNA |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | -1 |
| 3 | 0 |

I added an additional boolean column called consec_bs in my dataframe. I defined consec_bs as such: if the absolute value of the `df['DNA'] - df['DNA'].shift()` equals 2, consec_bs is True. Otherwise it's false. `df['DNA']` only takes values -1, 0, or 1. My code is as following:

```
def consec_bs(df):
    df['consec_bs'] = False
    temp = df.shift()
    df['diff'] = abs(df['DNA'] - temp['DNA'])
    df[df['diff'] == 2].loc['consec_bs'] = True
            
    return df
```

And the output df is

| index | DNA | consec_bs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | False |
| 1 | 1 | False |
| 2 | -1 | False |
| 3 | 0 | False |

However, consec_bs should return true at index 2.
I've tried `df[df['diff'] == 2]['consec_bs'].replace(False, True, inplace = True)`, but it doesn't update consec_bs.

Comment: In output df, thired value of consec_bs should be True if you are talking absolute value == 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a chained assignment problem. Do `df.loc[df['diff'] == 2, 'consec_bs'] = True` instead.

This problem is described in the pandas docs [(Why does assignment fail when using chained indexing?)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df["consec_bs"] = (abs(df['DNA'] - df['DNA'].shift()).eq(2))
print(df)

       index  DNA  consec_bs
    0      0    0      False
    1      1    1      False
    2      2   -1       True
    3      3    0      False
```